# Need to find the name of the current logfile being used in IIS

Tags: powershell, iis

I am needing to write a script to automate moving all of the IIS log files from a system that has been running for months.  This system consists of many web servers.

I am successful at getting the log directory moved to the new location, and then my script will move the other log files from the old directory to the new location with the exception of the current file.  It cannot move because there is a file in the destination with the same name.  (current log file.) I want to rename it, but do not want to rename all files in the directory.  I know I could use a wildcard, but would prefer to rename only that file.

What command can I use to find the name of the file, not the directory or path?  I have pieced this together from other smaller requests I have found on here and on the web.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$LogPath = "e:\Logs\IISlogs"
foreach($WebSite in $(get-website))
    {
    $logFile="$($Website.logFile.directory)\w3svc$($website.id)".replace("%SystemDrive%",$env:SystemDrive)
    } 
New-Item $LogPath -ItemType Directory


Set-ItemProperty “IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site” -name logFile.directory -value $LogPath
$path = $logpath+"\W3SVC1"
$Timeout = 60
$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
while (($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $Timeout) -and (-not (Test-Path -Path $path  ))) 
{

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    $tot = $timer.Elapsed.Seconds
    Write-Output -Message ("Still waiting for action to complete after " + $tot + " seconds upto " + $Timeout)
}
$timer.Stop()

Move "$($logfile)\*.*" $path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files have a time a date stamp. Filter the file name, sort by the time stamp descending, and select the first one.

For example:

```
$dir = "e:\Logs\IISlogs"
($latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | 
Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | 
Select-Object -First 1)
"Current log file details:  $($latest.name)"
Get-Content $latest
```

If you are saying the logs can be of a different name, then you need to specify the wildcard match for that in the path specification.

Comment: I tried that, but often IIS logs have two with the same modify date.

Comment: Do this all the way to the time stamp, not just the date. It is almost impossible, again, almost impossible for a file to had exactly the same date and time, in the same directory.

Comment: No worries. I have several automation tasks that required this kind of effort. So, I feel what you were experiencing.